# Setting up a network for VM guests

Tags: networking, virtual-machines

I have 4 windows VMs and a Mikrotik router vm  as guest on an ESXI 5 host server. I want to set up a network so that i can assign private IPs on the windows VM and make the Mikrotik router VM their default gateway. I know how to create a virtual switch for the physical NICs on the ESXI host. How do I create a network of the VMs where the windows VMs will sit behind the Mikrotik router.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the same vmware network for windows VMs and router's LAN interface. Set vmware dhcp off on this network and use dhcp from router.
- Use another vmware network for router WAN interface. On this network set vmware nat or bridge to allow external network access for router.